# Composer error when adding imager-x plugin

Tags: error-message, composer

```
Error: "https://composer.craftcms.com/p2/aws/aws-sdk-php.json" does not contain valid JSON
Parse error on line 1:
...pball\/6690347bc833"https:\/\/api.github
----------------------^
Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']'
```

Comment: If you load https://composer.craftcms.com/p2/aws/aws-sdk-php.json in a browser on the same server you're getting that message on, does it load for you? It loads fine and looks like valid JSON for me.

Comment: Thanks Brad yes it loads. I seem to have solved the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what version of Craft or Imager-X you're working with my first recommendation would be to do a composer update before adding Imager-X.

Next, I'd try deleting the 'vendor' directory and composer.lock file and running `composer install`

Comment: I think I did something like this and have solved the problem. Thanks